# Is there like a warning variant for buttons?

Tags: lightning-web-components

So I have button and I am using the variant to distinguish the different save state:

```
                <lightning:buttonStateful aura:id="save_logging" 
                                          class="slds-m-top_medium button"
                                          labelWhenOff="Save"
                                          labelWhenOn="Save"
                                          variant="brand"
                                          iconNameWhenOff=""
                                          iconNameWhenOn="utility:edit"
                                          state="{! v.isEdit_logging }"
                                          onclick="{! c.onSubmitClicked_logging}"/>
```

No edits:

[image]

Have edits:

[image]

Save successful:

[image]

Is there like a variant for saving or on error?  The existing variants are not very good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only get what's available to you through `lightning:buttonStateful`. The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-button-stateful/specification) shows the options you have for variant

> The variant changes the appearance of the button. Accepted variants include **brand, destructive, inverse, neutral, success, and text**

The options are limited to that. Of note, is that [styling hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/) are in beta and may help to provide more flexibility in changing things like this in the future for Salesforce provided components.

[image]